# Summing two columns in HH:MM:SS.000 in Excel

Tags: excel, time, milliseconds

It is most likely very trivial, but I simply cannot manage to sum two columns in the time format **hh:mm:ss.000**. ".000" indicate milliseconds. Summing 00:00:16.800 and 00:00:52.317 always result in zero instead of 00:01:09.117. I hope you can point me in the right direction and help troubleshooting this. Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

I have tried different Sum formulas and format styles.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256919/discussion-on-question-by-custos83-summing-two-columns-in-hhmmss-000-in-excel); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because Excel thinks your cells are text and it doesn't implicitly handle that when you use `SUM()`.

To work around this you can explicitly have Excel convert the cell value to a `TIMEVALUE` like so: `=SUM(TIMEVALUE(A2:B2))`.

When I test it with the explicit type conversion it works correctly:
[image: screenshot of spreadsheet with the described function result]

Here is my test spreadsheet: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Atp1-xJxROCWgkvluQLmy64OVIEj?e=HlAMpc

If this doesn't work for you can you try re-creating the issue in a test spreadsheet? You can do so by cloning mine using the `Edit a copy` button in the top right:
[image: image showing the edit a copy button on the spreadsheet webpage]